# Why simple INSERT statement returns error 1172

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and have a trouble with the simplest INSERT statement.

I have an associative table invoice_line_item, which have a compound primary key consisting of foreign keys from three tables:

```
Invoice_ID
Product_ID
Pet_ID
```

In addition there is a Quantity field.

In every row of the table if `Pet_ID!=1` then `Product_ID=1` and vice versa.

I want to add a row in the table, and I tried both through writing code, and just inserting data in MySQLYog Community, but error `'#1172:Result consisted of more than one row'` keeps coming up.

The code is:

```
INSERT INTO invoice_line_item (Invoice_ID, Product_ID, Pet_ID, Quantity)
      VALUES ('19','15','1','1').
```

I don't understand where additional rows come from.

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

I actually had a trigger, that returned incorrect rows, but I didn't figure it out until just about now. Once I droped the trigger, it worked perfectly. Thank you everyone for comments.

Comment: I was about to ask that!

Comment: Where did you code the rule `if Pet_ID!=1 then Product_ID=1 and vice versa` ? Because in the sample they are both 1

Comment: Yes, I've just figured it out. I did have a trigger I was testing on it. Thank you for your answers. I droped the trigger, and now it works perfectly.